# Shortening the following if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for this naive question. I'm trying to make this code a bit shorter, since it seems cumbersome to write this entire line out. Are there any ways to shorten the if statement?

```
if data.char == "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9":
    data.board[row][col] = int(data.char)
```

Comment: The existing code doesn't compile... so, `raise SyntaxError()`?

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If the code is already working as you expect, then use Code Review. In this case, the code currently has a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry about that. Just fixed it.

Comment: This code doesn't do what you think it does. It will always come out `True`, because it is equivalent to `(data.char == "1") or ("2") or ("3") or ...`, and `"2"` in a boolean context is treated as `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned by cco:

```
if data.char in "123456789"
    data.board[row][col] = int(data.char)
```

The **in** operator evaluates to true if it finds a variable in the specified sequence and false otherwise. It can be used for lists, strings, tuples and dictionaries. However the in will only check the keys of the dictionary - not the values.

If you wanted ints for example, you could declare a list of numbers and use that instead.

```
if num in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
    do something
```

or alternatively:

```
if num in range(1,9):
    do something
```

Comment: The main test you gave will have a false positive if `data.char` contains '23', '567', etc.

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```
import string
digits = set(string.digits) - {'0'}
if data.char in digits:
    data.board[row][col] = int(data.char)
```